# Joomla and JomSocial Intergration

Tags: authentication, joomla, jomsocial

We have a Joomla site and have Jomsocial installed.
We have enabled the JomSocial HelloMe module.

When we login and go to the home page of Jomsocial everything displays fine but we are getting a popup window asking us to login. If when logging in we select remember me this doesn't happen and everything works fine.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

This is either 1. The members module or 2. The auto refresh from the stream. You should post a support ticket so the guys at Jomsocial can fix it. http://www.jomsocial.com/forum/technical-issues

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the quick response.
Unfortunately our subscription has expired so we can't post on there at the moment. Any ideas why this may be happening
Rich